# OpenMP unpredictable overhead

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

I have a simple OpenMP code that runs four empty threads and reports the time:

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdio>
double start_time;

void process_thread() {
}

int main(){
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    start_time = 1000*((double)tv.tv_sec + 1e-6*(double)tv.tv_usec);
    printf("Beginning time: %.3fms   ",start_time-start_time);

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        process_thread();

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    double cur_time = 1000*((double)tv.tv_sec + 1e-6*(double)tv.tv_usec);
    printf("Finishing    time:  %.3fms\n\n",cur_time-start_time);
}
```

Without Openmp the running time is very small and consistent:

```
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.050ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.050ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.049ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.049ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.050ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.049ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.051ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.063ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.050ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.051ms
```

However, when I use OpenMP it takes much longer and the time becomes very inconsistent:

```
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.497ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 1.001ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.484ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 16.728ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 4.205ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 6.041ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 3.754ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 4.126ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.230ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.183ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 2.438ms
Beginning time: 0.000ms   Finishing time: 0.248ms
```

I was under the impression that OpenMP overheads would be in the range of 150ms but this seems to be way more.

I use a XEON E5 1650 with 6 cores with Ubuntu 12.04. I use gcc 4.6.3. I have tried other OpenMP configurations but static works best for this case.

What is responsible for this fluctuation? Is this the fault of the compiler, OpenMP runtime, OS, or something else? How can I improve it?

Comment: Where does it take more than 150ms? I see 16.728ms at most.

Comment: What else is running on your machine? You are likely starting six threads (despite only having four pieces of parallel work to do), and all the threads have to reach the barrier at the end of the parallel for. If any thread is held up by other tasks on the machine OpenMP can't leave the barrier.